# Premultiplied Alpha And Alpha Test

Tags: opengl, directx, shader, alpha

I have a shader that is supposed to work with either alpha blending or alpha testing, but the color values being passed in are premultiplied alpha values.

Is there an easy/standard way to have it produce the "correct" results for both alpha blending and alpha testing when using premultiplied alpha?

For example, if the final result of my shader is `RGBA(1,0,0,0.75)` straight alpha and therefore `RGBA(0.75,0,0,0.75)` premultiplied alpha, the result should be remain `RGBA(1,0,0,0.75)` when alpha testing.

Perhaps one option is "dividing out" the alpha channel if we are alpha testing, i.e. divide the `R` by `A` above so that we get `0.75/0.75 = 1.0`, our original red value.  But this becomes non-deterministic when the alpha goes to 0.

Say the back buffer is `RGBA(1,1,1,1)`, and i am rendering with a partially transparent green color `RGBA(0,1,0,0.75)` (straight alpha).  The color is passed in as premultiplied alpha as `RGBA(0,0.75,0,0.75)`.  When alpha *blending*, i blend using one + invsrcalpha and get a final color of `RGBA(0.25,1,0.25,1)`. So my green channel stays at 100%, because the back buffer had green at 100%, and so did my original green color, so no way to get less than 100% on the green channel.

When Alpha *testing*, there is no blending going on. Instead, my green color will be rendered straight to the back buffer as `RGBA(0,0.75,0,1)`.  But the color I wanted was `RGBA(0,1,0,1)`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the alpha test doesn't use the RGB values after all. So why do you want to recalculate them?

Comment: See updated question with example.  Hopefully that clarifies the basic issue.

Comment: I am still a bit confused about what you understand under alpha testing. Alpha testing was a feature of the FFP that allowed to discard pixels based on their alpha values. You can emulate this in the pixel shader by checking the alpha values. If you really need the other values, why don't you just try the division method, checking if alpha != 0.

Comment: Yeah, I think the for the case where alpha = 0, it doesn't matter that  I can't extract the original color, since it won't be drawn anyway.

Comment: When I say I need the other values, its because they're the color being returned from the pixel/fragment shader.

Comment: All components sould be summed up first. This would give RGBA(1,1.75,1,1.75), then comes the dividing out to the final straight screencolor, where you get RGBA(0.57,1,0.57,1)! How and why do you think your desired result could become RGBA(0,1,0,1)?

Comment: When rendering with premultiplied alpha the blend equation is `SRC + DEST * INVSRCALPHA`.  In this case `SRC` is `(0,0.75,0,0.75)`, `DEST` is `(1,1,1,1)`, and `INVSRCALPHA` is `0.25`.  So `DEST*INVSRCALPHA` becomes `(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)` and adding in `SRC` gives `(0.25,1,0.25,1)`.